# Nordic JavaScript encoding trouble

Tags: javascript, xslt, localization

I have this piece of JavaScript in a XSL stylesheet:

```
  function outputUrl() {
      var currentScripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
        var lastScript = currentScripts[currentScripts.length - 1];
        var fileUrl = window.location.href;
        var steps = fileUrl.split('/');
        var fileName = steps[steps.length - 1];
        lastScript.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(fileName),     lastScript);
  }
```

Now, this code displays the name of the current XML-file transformed by the stylesheet and it works perfectly well - until some of the nordic characters ÅÄÖ or åäö shows up in the filename. Then it will for instance display the letter Ö as %C3%96.

Any way to solve this?

Many thanks in advance:-)

/Paul

Answer (score 2):

In the JavaScript, `decodeURI(fileName)` should work as said in the [doc](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp)

Comment: So you can accept this answer to close the issue ;)

Answer (score -1):

Here is the working JavaScript code:

```
 function outputUrl() {
      var currentScripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
        var lastScript = currentScripts[currentScripts.length - 1];
        var fileUrl = window.location.href;
        var steps = fileUrl.split('/');
        var fileName = steps[steps.length - 1];
        var dec = decodeURI(fileName);
        lastScript.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(dec), lastScript);
      }
```

Comment: I think this is the same answer already given... It is better to accept an answer and/or to update it and/or to ask for the user to update it if it isn't to your satisfaction. Unless of course this answer is radically different, but I don't think it is.